# Angularjs Controller destructor

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have an AngularJs app. I use Controllers for some child scopes. In every Controller I can set a number of variables that belong to the corresponding Child Scope. When AngularJs instantiate a controller, there is a constructor where I can set a default value to my child-scope variables.

Do I have a controller "destructor"? How do I know when a controller is closing and the scope is being cleaned (destroyed by the $destroy function)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You have to listen to the `$destroy` *event*, e.g.:

```
function MyController($scope, ...) {
    ...
    $scope.$on("$destroy", function handler() {
        // destruction code here
    });
}
```

Relevant docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope

Comment: It is emitted by the `$scope`, so yes wherever you have access to the `$scope`, you can listen to it. Essentially the `$scope` is destroyed and emits this event; the controller is destroyed as a consequence of that, so it is somewhat indirect, but stable nonetheless.