# AngularJs - how to clean up controllers when navigating to a new route

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a controller that loads a lot of data with an observable. If I navigate away from that route and the view is removed from the page how do I get informed of that in my controller so that I can stop the data load in the controller?

I basically want a deactivate function or clean up function that gets fired when the controller is no longer needed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angularjs Controller destructor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24607140/angularjs-controller-destructor)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can listen for the `$destroy` event, and perform some clean-up/tear-down:

```
module.controller("SomeController", function($scope) {

    $scope.$on("$destroy", function() {
        // clean up here
    });
});
```

Resources:

- `$on`: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$on
- `$destroy`: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$destroy
- http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2013/07/16/angularjs-listening-for-destroy.aspx
- See #12 from [Top 18 most common AngularJS mistakes](https://www.toptal.com/angular-js/top-18-most-common-angularjs-developer-mistakes)

Comment: That's great, shame you have to inject the scope but not getting away from that I suppose.